# Finding words in a file that contains the word file and does not contain hypthens

Tags: unix

I am trying to find words in a file that contains the world file and does not contain hypthens. It looks correct to me but my output shows all the words with a hypthen and word file. My path name is/folder.file.txt
.

```
    cat /folder/file.txt | grep file[!-]*
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`!` isn't the right operator for negation. You need `^`.

```
file[!-]*
```

will match any string containing the word 'file' and zero or more instances of '!' or '-'.

So basically - anything with the word 'file' in it. If you want to negate a character class, you need to use `^`. But the `*` then allows for zero of the 'not patterns'.

If the dash is *immediately* after the word `file` then:

```
file[^-]
```

will match:

```
file1243
somefilefilea
```

but not:

```
file-1234
```

I think what you may be missing from your pattern is that `*` allows you to ignore part of the pattern.

```
^file[^-]*$
```

might do what you're after?

https://www.regex101.com/ will let you test regular expressions.

Comment: I sitll seem to be getting hythens in the output when I use ^.

Comment: file[^-] worked for me. ^file[^-]*$ gave me words that started with file.

Comment: Yes, it's a common gotcha that repeating patterns and negative patterns can be counterintuitive.